# I am using PaymentGateway where I have a array format data , how could i take each value from an array and use it that value in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is the format in which data is pass in Gatway Api URL.

```
   string postString = "key=" + keys +
            "&command=" + method +
            "&hash=" + Hashed +
            "&var1=" + var1;
```

After that the data is pass using post method and I get response in array format and when I convert using Jobject.Parse it getting error; how can I get every token value where as I am developed in C#.

```
 System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = 
        SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
        WebRequest myWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(Url);
        myWebRequest.Method = "POST";
        myWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        myWebRequest.Timeout = 180000;
        StreamWriter requestWriter = new 
        StreamWriter(myWebRequest.GetRequestStream());
        requestWriter.Write(postString);
        requestWriter.Close();

        StreamReader responseReader = new 
        StreamReader(myWebRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
        WebResponse myWebResponse = myWebRequest.GetResponse();
        Stream ReceiveStream = myWebResponse.GetResponseStream();
        Encoding encode = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
        StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(ReceiveStream, encode);
        string response = readStream.ReadToEnd();

        JObject account = JObject.Parse(response);      //Here getting Error

        String status = (string)account.SelectToken("transaction_details." + 
        var1 + ".status");
```

This is the format in which I am getting response

[image]

This is the error which is generate

[image]

Comment: You should format the response first and then convert it into JObject

Comment: Please paste the error

Comment: It is due to double quote " .

Comment: try replacing 1 double quote with two like this. response= response .Replace("\"", "\"\"");

Answer (score 0):

You will have to first replace 1 double quote with two and then Deserialize the response Object

```
     response= response .Replace("\"", "\"\""); 
     var res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response);
     JObject account = JObject.Parse(res);
```

Comment: In this line  JObject account = JObject.Parse(res); Getting error which u suggest error is.,  The best overloaded method match for 'Newtonsoft.Json.linq.Jobject.Parse(string)' has some invalid arguments.

Comment: " character is reserved in JSON and must be properly escaped to be used in strings

Comment: can u give me some correct code to convert and take every key value, Already 3 to 4 days past away and the boss is shouting now.Please buddy help me.Thanks a lot

Comment: i am using that two line which u provide  response= response .Replace("\"", "\"\""); 
     var res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response);   that generate same error

Comment: you error is because of <pre> tag.. your response in not JSON.

Comment: Did you tried getting pure JSON using request.Accept = "application/json";

Comment: can you send your API response as text? so that i can play around with it for desired result

Comment: var res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.ToString);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184247/discussion-between-amit-kumar-and-codeconstruct).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you get there, it seems the API is trying to deliver you something that looks good in a browser.

If you want to get back JSON, you have to communicate that wish:

```
myWebRequest.Accept = "application/json";
```

to have that property available, you have to cast your webrequest to a `HttpWebRequest` first:

Instead of:

```
WebRequest myWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(Url);
```

do

```
var myWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Url);
```

Comment: Generate error does not contain a definition of request, for this issue i want to  used System.Net.WebRequest but that namespace not provide any option for WebRequest then please suggest me how to provide that namespace

Comment: @amitkumar I have a hard time understanding your comment, but see my edit, I hope that was what you were asking for.

Comment: yes i m using it HttpWebRequest it also get same issue

Comment: Then you need to study your payment gateway's documentation more closely and if you are sure you got it right, you need to contact them and ask them this question. What you posted as the response you got is not JSON and is surely not meant to be parsed by a computer.